# Limit records on REST chatter feed

Tags: chatter, rest

I'm using the following (**non-APEX**) REST connection to retrieve chatter records from a unique chatter group (id.) How can I limit the number of chatter records retrieved? I only want to use the last 20 chatter records for a portal feed.

```
GET https://<my url>/services/data/v39.0/chatter/feeds/record/0F9G0000000PeqbKAC/feed-elements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd need to use a custom query for that.

```
/services/data/v40.0/query?q=SELECT+Body+FROM+FeedItem+WHERE+ParentId='0F9G0000000PeqbKAC'+LIMIT+20
```

Notice the `+LIMIT+20` clause at the end.

Comment: thanks. Works. We're providing an application connection allowing REST API to a 3rd party portal product (LifeRay.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `pagesize` query parameter. For example:

```
GET https://<my url>/services/data/v39.0/chatter/feeds/record/0F9G0000000PeqbKAC/feed-elements?pageSize=20
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resource_feeds_record.htm) describes the available query parameters.